# Python script that checks the requirements before installing any software(PHP,Java etc.,)

Tags: java, python

I am using python, and trying to develop a script that covers the below points

For example when we are trying to install particular software like PHP or Java etc., on linux machine and when we run the python script

```
   It should check the minimum requirements that needs to install that particular software(like PHP or Java that we will pass the this software name along with the script file)?
   Which version of that software is installed ?
```

I mean when we run the script with particular software name, the script should first find the requirements to install it and secondly whether the software is installed and if installed what is the version of that software ?

For example to know whether PHP installed or not on linux machine we will use `php -V` , 
also to find the version of java, we will use `java -version`.

so finally can anyone please let me know a basic concept of whether we can find the version of the software dynamically from a single python script along with requirements needed to install that particular software ?

Comment: You've described your solution within your own question?

Comment: ofcourse i thought that way, but i approached SO because whether i can get any dynamic code/script/ideas to implement the above points that is knwowing the mininum required softwares before installing any softwares we are trying to install

Comment: You could do my second option, on some distros.

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import system
phpstatus = system('php --version')
javastatus = system('java -version')

if phpstatus != 0:
    print 'Missing: PHP'
if javastatus != 0:
    print 'Missing: Java'
```

If any of the two are anything **BUT** 0 in the return value, you've got a missing module.
*(This is not optimal, you'll see plenty of unwanted text most likely but it's a start)*

List all installed software (buntu/debian):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
stdout, stderr = Popen(['dpkg', '--get-selections'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()
```

And then just loop through it and find what's installed vs what you require.
It all comes down to the basics, **what do you need**, you need a list of items that you require to be present in the system.. without that there's no way to automated what's missing because you can't develop something (as of today) that can understand what you will be expecting, what's installed and based on that what's missing.

You need: **a list of items that you demand to be installed**
Match that against, what's installed.

Comment: This is not a programming question per sae, it's a system administration question based on the OS you're using and what functions the OS provide, nothing here that Python will provide you with because it's on a lower-level of the OS functions to keep track of what the system installs and what's not installed.